# All anchors trigger postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET / AJAX enabled site with some jQuery UI code on it.

I'm having a problem where all anchors on the page trigger a postback, even plain HTML anchors I drop on the page. This is slowing things down considerably because page_load is firing twice and taking a long time for the page to load.

Even doing something as simple as:

```
<a href='foo.aspx'>Click me</a>
```

triggers a postback. I always thought a plain HTML anchor should just send the user to the new URL. And something else that's stranger...the plain links are actually SLOWER than the asp:LinkButton links on this page. (Huh?)

I haven't written any custom code to attach to all anchors on the page, though I do have a little jQuery that attaches to specific classes.

**UPDATE**

I've been tinkering with the code - and found out this is coming from the ToolKitScriptManager on the page! When I comment it out, regular links work properly!

When I define the ToolkitScriptManager like this, it triggers a postback for EVERY hyperlink on the page, which is not what I want:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="true" ScriptMode="Release">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

However, when I define it like this, regular hyperlinks work properly!

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Release">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML markup for such a tag when you inspect the element?

Comment: <a href='page.aspx'>Link Here</a>

Comment: Does this behavior occur in all browsers?

Comment: Confirmed in IE9 (offical browser here) and latest version of FireFox.

Comment: Do you see errors in your browser's console when script combining is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the problem by removing the extra attibutes on the ToolkitScriptManager. Now regular hyperlinks work the way they should, without triggering postbacks.